# Xcode, how to updates "Recent" projects

Tags: xcode

I have a list of projects i am working on, some of which are no longer relevant. I would like to be able to remove them from the "Recents" list that shows up when Xcode starts up.

**How to remove projects from "Recents" list?**

Please let me know

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can clear the entire recent projects list via the "File" -> "Open Recent" -> "Clear Menu" option within the file menu. (This applies to Xcode 4.x, but there's an equivalent in Xcode 3.x in the event it's not in the same location.)

Comment: How about clearing the same menu on in OSX Dock?  The Clear Menu method only clears File -> Open Recent, but not the dock right-click context menu. :(

Comment: In Xcode 7.x after doing above mentioned steps, just logout and login again will clear the dock right-click context menu

Answer (score 3):

File -> Open Recent Project -> Clear Menu